# VB.net - Strings: Splitting or regex

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, split

how can I split or use regex for the results of this msgbox to only get:
"maricruz.tinajero"

[image]

I thought about removing all new lines so it's only on one line and then using an index number to get the position of the string I want but im still trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about using `Split` or `Regex` for this:

```
 Dim idx As Integer = msg.LastIndexOf("\"c)
 Dim user As String = msg.SubString(idx + 1)
```

Comment: @T McKeown 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: and it's not a copy is it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:(str represents your string above)

```
Dim obj = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
```